# I have problem in stacking divs and then translating them

Tags: css

I have made 6 divs each stacked above each other.When the previous div is hovered all the other divs next to it are translated left by 150px. But they go in forward direction above each other and come backwards below the previous div and then sit above it in the end. I want them to come back above the previous div. How do i do it?

```css
#numberOne {
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
}

#numberTwo {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: -150px;
}

#numberThree {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  left: -300px;
}

#numberFour {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  left: -450px;
}

#numberFive {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  ;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -600px;
}

#numberSix {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  left: -750px;
}

#pileone,
#piletwo,
#pilethree,
#pilefour,
#numberSix {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  z-index: 8;
}

#numberOne:hover+#pileone {
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberTwo:hover+#piletwo {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberThree:hover+#pilethree {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberFour:hover+#pilefour {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberFive:hover+#numberSix {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(150px);
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
  <div id="numberOne">
  </div>
  <div id="pileone">
    <div id="numberTwo">
    </div>
    <div id="piletwo">
      <div id="numberThree">
      </div>
      <div id="pilethree">
        <div id="numberFour">
        </div>
        <div id="pilefour">
          <div id="numberFive">
          </div>
          <div id="numberSix">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you mean the rectangles should always keep the same position in the stacking order (whether they're moving or not), all you need to do is remove all the `z-index` properties.

```css
#numberOne {
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
}

#numberTwo {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -150px;
}

#numberThree {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -300px;
}

#numberFour {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -450px;
}

#numberFive {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  ;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -600px;
}

#numberSix {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: -3px -5px 16px black;
  background: #17141d;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: -750px;
}

#pileone,
#piletwo,
#pilethree,
#pilefour,
#numberSix {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

#numberOne:hover+#pileone {
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberTwo:hover+#piletwo {
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberThree:hover+#pilethree {
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberFour:hover+#pilefour {
  transform: translate(150px);
}

#numberFive:hover+#numberSix {
  transform: translate(150px);
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
  <div id="numberOne">
  </div>
  <div id="pileone">
    <div id="numberTwo">
    </div>
    <div id="piletwo">
      <div id="numberThree">
      </div>
      <div id="pilethree">
        <div id="numberFour">
        </div>
        <div id="pilefour">
          <div id="numberFive">
          </div>
          <div id="numberSix">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that is *not* what you mean, please let me know and I'll see what I can do.